# While building for visionOS Simulator, no library for this platform was found in

Tags: xcode, google-cloud-firestore, visionos

When I am trying to add Apple Vision as a destination I am getting the following errors.

**Error Message**

> While building for visionOS Simulator, no library for this platform
> was found in
> '/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dkslnywtifcaqzeiiiifmgmxxaqm/SourcePackages/artifacts/firebase-ios-sdk/FirebaseFirestoreInternal/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.xcframework'.

**Errors:**

[image]

When I check the derived data:

[image]

What I have tried

- Delete Derived data
- Clean Project
- Build Project
- Remove and Add Destination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [README of the repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk?tab=readme-ov-file#building-with-firebase-on-apple-platforms):

> Where supported, visionOS works as expected with the exception of **Firestore via Swift Package Manager where it is required to use the source distribution**.
>
> To enable the Firestore source distribution, quit Xcode and open the desired project from the command line with the `FIREBASE_SOURCE_FIRESTORE` environment variable: `open --env FIREBASE_SOURCE_FIRESTORE /path/to/project.xcodeproj`. To go back to using the binary distribution of Firestore, quit Xcode and open Xcode like normal, without the environment variable.

So you'll need to enable the source distribution, which probably also means the builds will take a lot longer than usual when using Swift Package Manager (so be patient).